# How to take data from a csv file and make a shopping list

Tags: java, arrays, csv, arraylist

I'm brand new to java coding and my objective is to take data from a CSV file which is formatted to be a shopping list eg:

```
Item,Category,Amount,Price,Location

Apple,Food,12,$1,Walmart

Grape,Food,3,$1,Walmart
```

I have to put the data into an array or ArrayList and have it outputted as a shopping list eg:

```
Item  | Category | Amount | Price | Location 

Apple |   Food   |   12   |   $1  | Walmart

Grape |   Food   |   3    |   $1  | Walmart

                Subtotal: $15
```

with all the items in each space going down.
at the end of each category, there is a subtotal count of the items in just that category.

so far I'm only at the stage where I can read the data from the CSV file and have it outputted as the 1st example and I'm feeling pretty lost now.

could I get some help on what direction to go from here?

my code right now is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fileName = "Project2.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName); 
try {
    Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
    while(inputStream.hasNext()) {
        String data = inputStream.next();
        System.out.println(data);
    }
    inputStream.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}}
```

Comment: As with all those types of tasks, do it the OOP way. That is, create dedicated classes (POJOs) that just represent data. Give them a `public static Foo parseLine(String line)` method and then feed it with the lines you read. With NIO (since Java 7), the reading and setting up is then essentially a 1-3 liner, super simple. For example a `ShoppingCartItem` class and then you do `Files.lines(Paths.get("myFile.txt")).map(ShoppingCartItem::parseLine).collect(Collectors.toList())` and you have a `List<ShoppingCartItem> cart`, your shopping cart. Done.

Comment: One big issue in your code right now is that you read token-wise. But you need to retain the line splitting. Read line-wise and then split the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just beginning to learn Java, you're probably looking for the `String.split()` command, which splits a string into an array that you'll iterate when outputting your results.

```
String[] fields=data.split(",");
```

If you're looking to develop a more robust solution, you'll want to use a library like `Apache Commons CSV` to address quoted content that might contain commas, which would split the data at unwanted points.

Answer (score 0):

So you can try Something like that :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "Project2.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName); 
    try {
         Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
         int subtotal = 0;
         int line = 0;
         while(inputStream.hasNext()) {
            String data = inputStream.next();
            String[] tab = data.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) System.out.print(tab[i] + "\t| ");
            System.out.println();
            if (line != 0) subtotal += Integer.parseInt(tab[2]) * Integer.parseInt(tab[3].substring(1));
            line ++;
          }
          System.out.println("\t Subtotal: $" + subtotal);
          inputStream.close();

       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```